# String concatenation with user input in C++

Tags: string, c++11, concatenation

I tried to write a code which gets an input from the user and concatenate with another string but it doesn't work well. The code is down below,

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string s1="Hi ";
    string s2;
    cin>>s2;
    s1=s1+s2
    cout<<s1;
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
this is how it works
```

Expected Output:

```
Hi this is how it works
```

But it didn't work as I expected. The output was:

```
Hi this
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You might want to learn about [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). The `>>` operator reads *space delimited* strings.

Comment: Thanks, @Someprogrammerdude. Now I got it corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'>>' reads space-delimited strings.
Now I found `getline` is used to read lines.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string s1="Hi ";
    string s2;
    getline(cin,s2);
    s1=s1+s2;
    cout<<s1;
    return 0;
}
```

Now I get the desired output.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, I have tried to use getline but now it's not reading the second string data. I am only getting Hi and the rest of the sentence is not printing

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s1="hi ";
    string s2;

    cout << "Enter string s2: ";
    getline (cin,s2);


    s1 = s1 + s2;

    cout << "concating both "<< s1;

    return 0;
}
```

here use this! this should help!